# R : regular expression to match pattern in only the first line

Tags: regex, r

In my R code, I have the following content of x as a result of lda prediction output.

```
[1] lamb
Levels: lamb cow chicken
```

I would like to capture the word "lamb" in the first line and not the second line. 
I had the following reg expression which did not work.

```
if (regmatches(x,regexec(".*?([a-z]+)",x))[[1]][2]=="lamb"){
  cat("It is a lamb") 
}
```

Instead, I also got the following error :-

```
Error in regexec(".*?([a-z]+)", x) : invalid 'text' argument
```

Anyone with help ? 
Thanks in advance.

mf

Comment: What do you mean in the first line and not in the second line?  You've got a factor there and the second "line" is the factor levels.

Comment: What you really want is `as.character(x)`. `x` is currently a factor. For more info check out `?factor`

Comment: If parameter in `regexec()` is an error, check its prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Direct Answer:**

It is a variable type error. See `?predict.lda` to learn why: The return object of a `predict()` when used with an object of class lda is a list. You just want the first element of the list, which is a factor for an object of type integer. Factors in R store some characters for every element in their level component, which can be accessed by `levels()` (Read `?factor` as well.). But what you want is to access the explicit value your factor shows, which can be acheived by `as.character()`. By the way: The second line does not get checked by the regex. It is just standard console output of a factor, see `?print.factor`.
Here's an example, based on the`predict.lda()` help page:

```
tr <- sample(1:50, 25)
train <- rbind(iris3[tr,,1], iris3[tr,,2], iris3[tr,,3])
test <- rbind(iris3[-tr,,1], iris3[-tr,,2], iris3[-tr,,3])
cl <- factor(c(rep("s",25), rep("c",25), rep("v",25)))
z <- lda(train, cl)
x_lda <-  predict(z, test)
# x_lda is a list
typeof(x_lda)
# The first element of the list, called "class", is a factor of type integer.
typeof(x_lda$class)
# Now we create a character vector from the factor:
as.character(x_lda$class)
```

With an explicit character object, your code works for me:

```
x <- "lamb"
regmatches(x,regexec(".*?([a-z]+)",x))[[1]][2]=="lamb"
[1] TRUE
```

So you need to coerce your object to character, and then use it as the "text" argument for the regexec function.

**Actual Answer:**

There are better ways to do this.

1. You nest and chain a lot of functions in one line. This is barely readable and makes debugging hard.
2. If you know that the output will always consist of certain elements (especially, since you know the input of your lda prediction and therefore know the different factor levels beforehand), you can simply check them by `==` and maybe `any()` (continuing with the example from before):

   ```
   levels(cl)
   [1] "c" "s" "v"
   any(as.character(x_lda$class)=="c")
   [1] TRUE
   ```

   See the help file for `?any`, if you don't know what it does.
3. Finally, if you just want to print "It is a lamb" in the end, and your output will **always** just have *one* element, you can simply use `paste()`:

   ```
   paste("It is a", as.character(x))
   [1] "It is a lamb"
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much zerweck. This solved the problem. And not only that, i've learnt a lot from this answer alone. -mf

Comment: happy to help. if you want, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark below the voting arrows.